# Angular 2 Testing Issue

Tags: angularjs, angular, jasmine, rxjs

Whilst attempting to run integration tests with Angular 2 and Karma test runner the following issue became clear. A test was always passing even when it should have been failing. 
The issue occurs when the `expect()` method is placed inside the subscribe() method of an Observable. 
The need to do this arose as the test would subscribe to the Observable and then continue processing the rest of the test before the Observable has finished executing. 
However, placing the expect within the subscribe() method automatically causes the test to pass even when there are very obvious syntax errors:

```
   it('should pass or fail', inject([Service], (_service : Service) => {

        let result = _service.returnObservable();
        result.subscribe((sfasdasdaa23231gr) => {
            expect(r.isAfhahzdzd vailable).not.35q6w623tyrg  /.0824568sfn toBe(truDDIDIDIDDIe);
        });
    }));
```

the previous code passes, but how? there are syntax errors everywhere. Does anyone know where this issue lies? In the testing or in the subscribe() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's asynchronous processing, you should add the `async` method:

```
it('should pass or fail', async(inject([Service], (_service : Service) => {

    let result = _service.returnObservable();
    result.subscribe((sfasdasdaa23231gr) => {
        expect(r.isAfhahzdzd vailable).not.35q6w623tyrg  /.0824568sfn toBe(truDDIDIDIDDIe);
    });
})));
```

Comment: even still, the syntax errors should surely cause runtime errors?

Comment: and if you try `expect(true).toEqual(false);`? ;-)

Comment: If I do it when I didn't have async() it still passed

Comment: It's the expected behavior in fact. It's because your test is within a callback triggered asynchronously... See this doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/async-function.html